# UIPopoverController hierarchy/inheritance with other ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a BaseController and three subclass ViewControllers.  In each of the subclass ViewControllers, a query is made to the sqlite database to get the information.  I want to add a longPress feature at the BaseController level to pop up a UIPopoverController.

So then I have a subclass of UITableViewController to be used with the UIPopoverController to display the data.  Do I need to get the information from the sqlite database in my subclass of UITableViewController to have that information be displayed in UIPopoverController?  It seems redundant since my 3 subclasses of the BaseController already have the data, and now I just want to have that data in a UIPopoverController, as well as add additional functionality like when a row is selected from the UIPopovercontroller.

Answer (score 0):

The UIPopoverController is a view controller. 
SO:
display the table.view in the UIPopoverController.

As far as adding functionality to a row press:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 // in here write what happens. if its row specific write:
  /// if (indexPath.row == ROWNUMBER){method} (rows start at 0)
}
```

and all of this goes in the .m file of the tableView you are presenting